# Maximum Directional Derivatives using tangent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

If $y=-2x+1$ is an equation of the line tangent to the the curve $f(x,y)=2$ at point $(1,3)$ and $f_x(1,3)=4$.
Then find the maximum directional derivative of $f(x,y)$ in the direction of $(1,3)$.

Since the funntion $f(x,y)$ is not given how do I proceed with this?

Comment: The maximum directional derivative is always perpendicular to the function's level surface.

Comment: Is an equation *what* to the curve? Are you missing a word here?

Comment: @Allawonder yes fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean directional derivative *at* the point $$(1,3)$$. For that, you can use the fact that if $f$ is differentiable, then:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\hat{u}}(1,3)=f_x(1,3)u_1+f_y(1,3)u_2$$
Here $\hat{u}=\left(u_1,u_2\right)$ is our direction. We also know from properties of the inner product:
$$
f_x(1,3)u_1+f_y(1,3)u_2=\vec{\nabla}f(1,3)\cdot\left(u_1,u_2\right)=\Vert{\vec{\nabla}f(1,3)}\Vert\overset{=1}{\overbrace{\Vert{\hat{u}}\Vert}}\cos{(\theta)}
$$
Meaning the maximum occurs when $\theta=0$ or in other words, when $\hat{u}=\frac{\vec{\nabla}f(1,3)}{\Vert\vec{\nabla}f(1,3)\Vert}$. So, all we have to do is calculate $f_y(1,3)$.

We know that $y=2x+1$ (I assume the minus is a mistake since the point does not lie on this line) implies $f(x,y(x))=2$. Define $g(x)=f(x,2x+1)\equiv 2$, and use the chain rule to get:
$$
g'(1)=0=f_x(1,3)+2f_y(1,3)\overset{f_x(1,3)=4}{\overbrace{\Longrightarrow}}f_y(1,3)=-2
$$
So the direction in which the directional derivative is maximal will be:
$$
\hat{u}_{{\rm max}}=\frac{(4,-2)}{\sqrt{16+4}}=\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{20}},-\frac{2}{\sqrt{20}}\right)
$$

Comment: The answer should be a number, not a unit vector.  Since $f_x=4$, that gives you the first component., but the gradient vector will be in the direction you give.

Comment: This is the direction in which $f_{\hat{u}}(1,3)$ will be maximal. finding the right $\hat{u}$ we just need to finish by writing: $f_{\hat{u}}(1,3)=4\cdot\frac{4}{\sqrt{20}}-2\cdot\frac{-2}{\sqrt{20}}$.